# Is test player for Apple Game Center done as for real user?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am doing Game Center integration in my app.

I was reading:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit%5fGuide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html)

There it is said:

> Important: Always create new test accounts to test your game in Game Center. Never use an existing Apple ID.

Do they mean that I should make new account just as for real "live" person playing, or Apple have some other procedure ?

So my question is how to make test accounts for Game Center ?

Only option that I see is to register another email address with new user, but to me it look like wrong way.

**UPDATE:**
I have make new user account and called it sandbox1.
I hope that this is the right was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a test user by logging into iTunesConnect, and clicking on Manage Users. You can then select from creating an "iTunesConnect User" or a "Test User".

Reference: [iTunesConnect Developer Guide - Test User accounts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)

Comment: For what is this user used exactly ? I see no explanation on iTunes page. This is confusing for me, because if it is a test user for game center, why do they asks for birth, name, email. I mean it is test user, it doe not exist.

Comment: Test users are for testing Game Center and in-app purchases in sandbox mode. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

Comment: It look like it is correct. Anyway I as confused when then you need to put info like: birth, name, email. Apple could have done this better.